# iTunes rejected binary

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I received an email from apple after uploading my app to itunes connect with this in it:

**TestFlight SDK** - TestFlight no longer requires an SDK to enable beta testing, crash reporting and analytics. To continue using TestFlight, set up Beta Testing in iTunes Connect and remove references to the SDK from the following executables: myapp.app/myapp

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Any solutions? 
Thanks In advance.

Note: I don't have Old TestFlight SDK in project.

Comment: The last line says it all: You cant use the old SDK for TestFlght any more. If you want to beta test, you must use Apple Itunes Connect.

Comment: Remove all reference to TestFlight from your project. It's no longer needed. Apple are pointing you to the solution in their repsonse

Comment: @logixologist I don't have Old Testflight SDK in application.

Comment: If you received this through 'resolution center', I'd advice you to simply reply and ask. From my experience they answer back rather quickly.

Comment: @bauerMusic Its not from resolution center. As I upload build, I got this mail from apple.

Comment: @OMK they apparently think you do :)

Comment: @OMK In that case, it could well be one of the iTunesConnect 'funny moments' (of which we have plenty). Try to simply load a new build, or wait a few hours and try again. I have similar issue, called Apple, they didn't know the reason, was on iTunesConnect server side. Was fine a day later.

Comment: @bauerMusic Thanks. I will try latter.

Comment: @bauerMusic It worked after I update Analytics framework which I am using from long time (From first app store release of application).